# Guzzle 6 with google OAuth not working.?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, guzzle6

I'm trying to follow a tutorial [here](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/blob/master/examples/server/php/app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php)
using Satellizer and angularjs as front-end and laravel & Guzzle 6 for back-end with social authentication . I have problem using Guzzle to query user profile information: here is my php code in my controller :

```
$accessTokenUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
    $peopleApiUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/openIdConnect';
    $params = [
        'code' => $request->input('code'),
        'client_id' => $request->input('clientId'),
        'client_secret' => 'my-client-secret',
        'redirect_uri' => $request->input('redirectUri'),
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    ];
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $accessTokenResponse = $client->post($accessTokenUrl, ['form_params' => $params]);
    $accessToken = json_decode($accessTokenResponse->getBody()->getContents(),true)['access_token'];

    try {

//            $profileResponse = $client->get($peopleApiUrl, ['header' => ['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,]]); -->not working
            $profileResponse = $client->get($peopleApiUrl,['oauth_token'=>$accessToken]);
        } catch (RequestException $e) {
            return response()->json($e);
        }
```

I cannot connect to get user profile and the error msg :

```
ClientException in Middleware.php line 69: Client error: 403

in Middleware.php line 69
at Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(object(Response)) in Promise.php line 199
at Promise::callHandler('1', object(Response), array(object(Promise), object(Closure), null)) in Promise.php line 152
at Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure}() in TaskQueue.php line 60
at TaskQueue->run() in CurlMultiHandler.php line 96
at CurlMultiHandler->tick() in CurlMultiHandler.php line 123
at CurlMultiHandler->execute(true) in Promise.php line 240
at Promise->invokeWaitFn() in Promise.php line 217
at Promise->waitIfPending() in Promise.php line 261
at Promise->invokeWaitList() in Promise.php line 219
at Promise->waitIfPending() in Promise.php line 62
.......
```

anyone have same problem and found a way to fix it ? please help. 
thanks.

Comment: Does your trace go furhter back?  Does your code sample "crash" on the first request (authentication) or the second request (API access)?  What happens when you place your client into the 'debug' mode?

Comment: Thanks Shaun. I changed the link (bellow answer) and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who have the same issue trying to follow Satellizer example for Laravel and php. I change the Google API url (from the doc) and now I can get the user profile info.

```
$peopleApiUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo';  // works with this link
```

the link for in the example maybe for older version .